# Display centre movieClip - Flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

How to have that movieClip created to be created at the centre of the screen?

Thank,

http://pastebin.com/AkrW6e56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
cp.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - cp.width/2;
cp.y = stage.stageHeight/2 - cp.height/2;
```

Comment: isn't there anything like "horizontalCenter"? as in flex4

Comment: is the swf embedded at 100% height/width in the browser?

Comment: It should work - here's an example: http://clearmpls.com/temp/fullbrowser/ with the source code downloadable from here: http://clearmpls.com/temp/fullbrowser/fullbrowser.zip (example is in Flash, but it just uses a document class with an external .as file)

Comment: nope, it should still work. If you want to send over your codebase, I can take a look at it. Otherwise, it's tough to debug since, based on the code you posted, this should do it (unless there's some invisible elements that go beyond the bounds of your cp instance).